# dismissModalViewController then popViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have been searching for a solution to my problem but haven't found anything so far.

I have a UINavigationController with a stack of UIViewControllers (this is all within a TabbarController, if that is relevant). At the last ViewController, I want to send an email:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *emailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
// fill out emailVC properties ...
[self presentModalViewController:emailVC animated:YES];
```

Then in the delegate after the email has been sent, I want to close the email viewcontroller and also pop off the last viewcontroller in the NavigationController stack:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error
    {
        // save some variables here ...
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // This line works by itself
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // this line causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

However, the last line causes a crash somewhere.
I have checked the ViewController stack before and after. The last viewController correctly gets removed from the list.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome. The problem could lie somewhere else in my code I want to make sure I have this part ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try initiating the pop delayed

**iOS 3 and later solution**

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError *)error
{
    [...]
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doThePop) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.40];
    [...]
}

- (void)doThePop
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

You may want to fine-tune the delay.

**iOS 5 and later solution**

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [...]
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }];
    [...]
}
```

Even though this seems a bit hackish, it should work.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you so much. Do you know why it works?

Comment: Actually, I had such problem before and solved it this way. I am afraid I do not **know** why it works, I just had this idea, tested it and it worked. I think the dismiss of that modal view needs to be entirely done to keep a proper viewController stack, allowing the pop to function properly. Whenever I encounter things that seem odd and should be functioning in connection with animated UIKit tasks but are not working, I try it this way.

Comment: This doesn't generally work in iOS 5, because self.navigationController is null for a modal viewcontroller :(

Comment: @Adam not sure what you are referring to. The method drafted above is not invoked on the modally displayed viewcontroller but on the delegate of the mailComposeViewController. That delegate is a viewController described as being part of a navigation stack within the question.

Comment: The question starts out generic, then goes specific. Your answer is  awesome, and ALMOST but NOT QUITE an answer to the generic problem. This question is a top google hit for the generic problem :(. Generic solution works if you "save" a reference to the presentingViewController, and then use the block method ... but it also seems to work if you just do the WRONG thing and directly perform a "popViewController" - I think Apple has added special case code to handle this situation.